# Launch local application url from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, protocols

I have a local application url protocol: `myapp:///`

In the terminal, when I do `open myapp:///`, the application launches. As I understand, this command is a bit different from different OS. Also, if I go to a browser and type `myapp:///` I also launch the application.

My question is: can I do this in AngularJS by making some kind of request?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by having a link that the user can click. However, the protocol must be added in `app.js`:

```
app.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|myapp):/);
}]);
```

This whitelists `myapp:///` - otherwise AngularJS will prefix it with `unsafe`.